How to use table.cell() to handle this case using QuestPDf library?
i face a case when deal with table cells , if i have a cell with 4 span vertical and 2 span horizontal and have only two objects . i handle that before by using 2 rows for objects values + 2 empty rows.
what if i handle that to make each object take space of 2 span vertical , thats will make me dont need to display the remaining rows as empty , can it handled ?
this is the code i have used
report demo
table.Cell().RowSpan(maxListCount).ColumnSpan((uint)myProperities).Column(column =>{
int renderedRows = 0;
foreach (var complexItem in list)
{                                        
    column.Item().Row(row =>
    {
        foreach (var subHeader in header.ChildHeaders)
        {              
            var subHeaderValue = subHeader.Accessor(complexItem);
row.RelativeColumn().Element(mergedBlock).AlignCenter().Text(subHeaderValue?.ToString() ?? string.Empty);
    
        }
    });

    renderedRows++;  
}
while (renderedRows < 4)
{
    column.Item().Row(row =>
    {
        row.RelativeColumn().Element(mergedBlock).AlignCenter().Text("");
    });

    renderedRows++;
}});

